# Can't import Weka in Python

Tags: python, weka

I've tried import weka package in Pycharm. But it got an error.

This is for Python 3.7.4 on windows 10. And I've installed java bridge and Weka successfully.

```
Package             Version
------------------- -------
arff                0.9
javabridge          1.0.18
numpy               1.17.3
pandas              0.25.2
pip                 19.3.1
python-dateutil     2.8.0
python-weka-wrapper 0.3.15
pytz                2019.3
setuptools          40.8.0
six                 1.12.0
weka                1.0.6
```

and I type:
`import weka.core`
and get the error:

```
  File "C:/Users/dell/PycharmProjects/lab2/Source.py", line 2, in <module>
    import weka.core
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'weka.core'
```

So how to fix it? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

`weka.core` is not a Python module, as the error states.

What are you trying to achieve with this import?

If you are trying to import the `jvm` module (eg for starting/stopping the JVM), then do something like `import weka.core.jvm as jvm`.